# unable to send mail through jenkins ,getting exceptions

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-cli

I am trying to setup Email Notification in Jenkins

But When I click on Test Configuration , I am getting below error

Refer Attached Screenshot as well as below Error

Pls Help I am stuck here.

```
sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(Unknown Source)
Caused: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(Unknown Source)
Caused: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.configureSSLSocket(SocketFetcher.java:507)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.getSocket(SocketFetcher.java:238)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1900)
Caused: javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.gmail.com, port: 465;
  nested exception is:
    javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1934)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:638)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:317)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:176)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:125)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:194)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:124)
    at hudson.tasks.Mailer$DescriptorImpl.doSendTestMail(Mailer.java:581)
    at java.lang.invoke.MethodHandle.invokeWithArguments(Unknown Source)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function$MethodFunction.invoke(Function.java:343)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvoke(Function.java:184)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvokeAndServeResponse(Function.java:117)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$1.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:129)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:58)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:715)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:845)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$5.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:248)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:58)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:715)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:845)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:649)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.service(Stapler.java:238)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:841)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1650)
    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:135)
    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1637)
    at hudson.security.csrf.CrumbFilter.doFilter(CrumbFilter.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1637)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:84)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:90)
    at hudson.security.HudsonFilter.doFilter(HudsonFilter.java:171)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1637)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.compression.CompressionFilter.doFilter(CompressionFilter.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1637)
    at hudson.util.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:82)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1637)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.DiagnosticThreadNameFilter.doFilter(DiagnosticThreadNameFilter.java:30)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1637)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:533)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:524)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:190)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1595)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:188)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1253)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:168)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:473)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1564)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:166)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1155)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:564)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:317)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:251)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:279)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.Invocable.invokePreferred(Invocable.java:128)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.Invocable$InvocableExecutor.invoke(Invocable.java:222)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:294)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:199)
    at winstone.BoundedExecutorService$1.run(BoundedExecutorService.java:77)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you configure your gmail to access low security apps. Check this if you are not done. Update the plugin if you have any new update for plugin. you are facing certification issues if you see the error.

Follow steps for certification issue:

You need to import certificate for smtp.gmail.com

1) Enter command to view this certificate

```
C:\openssl\bin\openssl.exe s_client -connect smtp.gmail.com:465
```

2) Copy the Copy and save the lines between 
"-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----"

"-----END CERTIFICATE-----" into a file,eg:-gmail.cer

3) Use this command to export
     keytool -import -alias smtp.gmail.com -keystore "%JAVA_HOME%/jre/lib/security/cacerts" -file C:\Users\ca\Desktop\gmail\gmail.cer

4)  Enter password chageit

5) Click yes to import the certificate

6) Restart java

Hope it works for you

Comment: HI Chandra,
Thanks for your response,
I tried the above mentioned steps.
Entry for the generated certifcate was made at location C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\security

But still Jenkins is unable to send Email.

PFB Exception is try using SSL :
sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

I get below error without SSL
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out

 at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)

Pls <<HELP>>